# apachectl start can't find httpd but it is there?

Tags: linux, apache, unix, installation, webserver

Complete newbie to the Unix and Apache world.

Just configured and installed Apache (successfully as far as I know) on a remote server, via X-Win32 SSH.

In the bin directory I see "httpd" listed.

To start the web server my provided instructions for the server state:

> From your installation Apache directory type, './bin/apachectl start'.

However, I get the following error (11-14 just showing it is there):

```
server.edu(11): ls
bin     cgi-bin conf    htdocs  icons   include libexec logs    man     proxy
server.edu(12): cd bin
server.edu(13): ls
ab              apxs            dbmmanage       htpasswd        logresolve
apachectl       checkgid        htdigest        httpd           rotatelogs
server.edu(14): cd ..
server.edu(15): ./bin/apachectl start
./bin/apachectl: apache/bin/httpd: not found
./bin/apachectl start: httpd could not be started
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

**EDIT** @h4b0

```
server.edu(98): pwd
/home/scf-25/gmcnulty/apache_1.3.42/apache

server.edu(99): ls -l bin/httpd
-rwxr-xr-x   1 gmcnulty     28880 May 24 22:12 bin/httpd
```

**EDIT2** @h4b0

```
server.edu(102): ls
ab              apxs            dbmmanage       htpasswd        logresolve
apachectl       checkgid        htdigest        httpd           rotatelogs

server.edu(103): cd ../..

server.edu(104): ls
ABOUT_APACHE            NOTICE                  README                  cgi-bin                 htdocs
INSTALL                 NWGNUenvironment.inc    README-WIN.TXT          conf                    icons
LICENSE                 NWGNUhead.inc           README.configure        config.layout           logs
Makefile                NWGNUmakefile           WARNING-WIN.TXT         config.status           src
Makefile.tmpl           NWGNUtail.inc           apache                  configure

server.edu(105): ./apache/bin/apachectl start
fopen: No such file or directory
httpd: could not open error log file apache/apache/logs/error_log.
./apache/bin/apachectl start: httpd could not be started
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Check permissions for `httpd`
- Does `apache/bin/httpd` actually exist? Show `pwd` output from directory at line 11

Comment: Please see the edit above. (Doesn't (13) shows that it is there? or am I misunderstanding?) thank you.

Comment: I wanted to make sure if `apache` is actual dir name. In line 14, go to `../..` and in line 15 do `./apache/bin/apachectl start`

Comment: Yes, it is. The output is not what I wanted ;p Check your $PATH variable (`echo $PATH`) - if there's no apache direcotry, add it. I'm not sure which though - try `/home/scf-25/gmcnulty/apache_1.3.42/apache` and `/home/scf-25/gmcnulty/apache_1.3.42/apache/bin` (`export PATH=$PATH:[path1]:[path2]`)

Comment: no not in the path variables, hmm.... does export work with that syntax using xWin32 in SSH?

Comment: it should: `export PATH=$PATH:/home/scf-25/gmcnulty/apache_1.3.42/apache:/home/scf-25/gmcnulty/apache_1.3.42/apache/bin`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11730/discussion-between-h4b0-and-greg-mcnulty)